# Bit rate error when trying to dial out to an ISDN line using Polycom XML API

Tags: api, video-conferencing

I am having a problem connecting to an ISDN line using Polycom's XML API on an RMX_2000. Below is the request I am sending, and the response. I can do the same action from the RMX Manager, for the same number, in the same conference, and it works. When I trace the XML from the RMX Manager, I get an ADD_PARTY request that looks exactly like my constructed request, except with a lot more elements. I've reviewed and don't see any that seem like they could be relevant, and I am loath to manually code every single element, knowing that it is a long shot that it will even help. The same request (variant) works fine for IP and registered number requests, but no matter what I do, always get the bit rate error below. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<TRANS_CONF_1>
  <TRANS_COMMON_PARAMS>
    <MCU_TOKEN>304</MCU_TOKEN>
    <MCU_USER_TOKEN>304</MCU_USER_TOKEN>
    <MESSAGE_ID>1</MESSAGE_ID>
  </TRANS_COMMON_PARAMS>
  <ACTION>
    <ADD_PARTY>
      <ID>18466</ID>
      <PARTY>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <NAME>isdn</NAME>
        <PHONE_LIST>
          <PHONE1>12345678910</PHONE1>
        </PHONE_LIST>
        <INTERFACE>isdn</INTERFACE>
        <CONNECTION>dial_out</CONNECTION>
        <MEET_ME_METHOD>party</MEET_ME_METHOD>
        <NUM_TYPE>taken_from_service</NUM_TYPE>
        <MULTI_RATE>auto</MULTI_RATE>
        <ALIAS>
          <NAME>12345678910</NAME>
          <ALIAS_TYPE>323_id</ALIAS_TYPE>
        </ALIAS>
        <VIDEO_BIT_RATE>automatic</VIDEO_BIT_RATE>
        <ENHANCED_VIDEO>false</ENHANCED_VIDEO>
        <UNDEFINED>false</UNDEFINED>
      </PARTY>
    </ADD_PARTY>
  </ACTION>
</TRANS_CONF_1>
```

Here is the response:

```
<RESPONSE_TRANS_CONF>
    <RETURN_STATUS>
        <ID>1015</ID>
        <DESCRIPTION>Conference bit rate must be set to a minimum of 128Kbps to enable ISDN participant connection</DESCRIPTION>
        <YOUR_TOKEN1>0</YOUR_TOKEN1>
        <YOUR_TOKEN2>0</YOUR_TOKEN2>
        <MESSAGE_ID>1</MESSAGE_ID>
        <DESCRIPTION_EX></DESCRIPTION_EX>
    </RETURN_STATUS>
    <ACTION>
        <ADD_PARTY/>
    </ACTION>
</RESPONSE_TRANS_CONF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a little help from someone at Polycom, I found out that the following node is required for this:

auto

I added that to the PARTY node, and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of troubleshooting and wiresharking on this error I found a combination of 2 properties being the issue

Reservation object needs

```
  <TRANSFER_RATE>384</TRANSFER_RATE>
```

Party object needs

```
        <NET_CHANNEL_NUMBER>auto</NET_CHANNEL_NUMBER>
```